# Microsoft Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have 1 table with **STOCK CODE** and **CONTRACT VENDOR**
I have 1 table with **PURCHASE ORDER**, **STOCK CODE**, **VENDOR**, AND **CONTRACT**

[image: TABLES]

I need a formula that uses the stock code from the Purchase order table to search the stock code - contract vendor table and return whether or not a vendor is one of many available contract vendors for that stock code.

Trying to end with a result that looks like this:

[image: CONTRACT YES OR NO]

Answer (score 3):

You can use:
`=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,B13,$B$2:$B$10,C13)>0,"Yes","No")`
Countifs will return 1 when there is a match Stock code and Contract Vendor with the purchase Table
When no match (if only Stock code) Countifs will return 0
If will return Yes when True and No when False
B13 is the Stock Code
C13 is the Vendor in the Purchase Table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like this one:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$10/(($B$2:$B$10=G2)*($A$2:$A$10=F2)),1)),"Yes","No")
```

[image]